# How To: Custom Edit Column name and Value in a Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I am kind of a newbie to MVC and Telerik and working on a project that involves both of them, the problem am facing currently is:
Am using teleirk Grids extension with Grid Method (DataTable) bound to a DataTable:

```
<% var table = ViewData["NewDesigns"] as DataTable;
```

`Html.Telerik() .Grid(table) .Name("oi") .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(100)) .Groupable() .Sortable() .Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(r => r.category).Title("Category"); }) .Render(); %>`

The grid is being displayed fine but there are two things that I want to do:

1. Change the column name to my custom heading/title
2. Eid Datatable content before printing it in a grid: 
   *For e.g.*: if id column has a value ‘21’, I want to print it in as hyper-link  21

I've spent time in telerik help files and learned a lot but not able to find answer of these, ld appericiate if someone here could help me out.

*DataTable Object:*

```
    ordr    {myprod.Models.Orders}  myprod.Models.Orders addrss null    string cntact   null    string custmrNam    null    string dlivrdn  null    string dsignr   null    string dsignId  null    string mail null    string id   null    string rdrCd null   string rdrdn    null    string quantity null    string siz  null    string status   null    string ttalPric null    string twn  null    string usrId    null    string'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example with custom titles and custom templates might help:

```
Html.Telerik()
    .Grid(table)
    .Name("ordersInum")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(typeof(Int32), "ID").Title("Row ID").Template(Html.ActionLink(item.ID, "Detail", new { r.ID }));
        columns.Bound(typeof(string), "Name").Title("Product").Template(@<text>
                <img src="images/product.png" />
                @item.Name
            </text>);
        columns.Bound(typeof(Double), "Price").Title("Price in $");
        columns.Bound(typeof(DateTime?), "OrderDate").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(80);
    })
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(100))
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Render();
```

Comment: Thank-you for reply, But adding this line[.Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(r => r.price).Title("Price in $"); })]
is giving this compilation error:
"CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: @Maven: I wasn't able to test my sample because I didn't have a matching data source to bind to the grid. Either start with a working page and work step by step by adding small pieces from my sample and fixing all the problems that occur, or paste all the details of your data table and the full grid definition that doesn't work.

Comment: yea sure: :)
<% var table = ViewData["NewDesigns"] as DataTable;
Html.Telerik() .Grid(table) .Name("oi") .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(100)) .Groupable() .Sortable() .Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(r => r.category).Title("Category"); }) .Render(); %>

Comment: DataTable Object:  
    'ordr {myprod.Models.Orders} myprod.Models.Orders
  addrss null string
  cntact null string
  custmrNam null string
  dlivrdn null string
  dsignr null string
  dsignId null string
  mail null string
  id null string
  rdrCd null string
  rdrdn null string
  quantity null string
  siz null string
  status null string
  ttalPric null string
  twn null string
  usrId null string'

Comment: @Maven: Would you mind adding these two pieces to your question. It's not really readable as a comment.

Comment: @Maven: I haven't used the Telerik grid with a data table yet. But i think you have to replace `columns.Bound(r => r.category)` with `columns.Bound("category")` or `columns.Bound(typeof(string), "category")`. But then I don't see no column called _category_ in your table. So you probably better write `columns.Bound(typeof(string), "custmrNam")`.